# How to stop Visual Studio from closing the solution when changing the active Git repo

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution that contains projects which are contained in several Git repositories. The `.sln` file is in one of the repos. It basically looks like this:

```
Repo1
  Solution.sln
  ProjectA
Repo2
  ProjectB
  ProjectC
```

Using the Git source control provider that comes with Visual Studio 2015 kind of works.

But sometimes when I switch the active Git repository using the “Connect” pane in Team Explorer (Ctrl+Alt+F4), Visual Studio will close the solution, but sometimes it will not.

How can I stop Visual Studio from closing the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Team Explorer makes an assumption that your .sln is contained in one repo.  Imagine what would happen if someone clones just Repo1 but not Repo2, or clones them into different relative paths than you expect.

In your situation, I would argue that you ought to either

- Put all of your projects in one repo OR
- Have ProjectB and ProjectC produce NuGet packages that you consume from ProjectA

Comment: Although this is not an answer to my question, you are probably right.

Comment: My need is similar to the original question and this answer doesn't help me either.  I want to have several library projects each in it's own repo. Then there will be a solution which contains a website project (in it's own repo) and contains the other projects.  This kinda works, but when using the VS Git plugin and switching repos it closes the solution (as mentioned).  I want to easily be able to edit each of the projects in the solution so consuming NuGet packages is not what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for and easy way to commit on a project level and it go to the right repo.

Comment: I have one master git repo that has three subrepositories. So whatever I do, I cannot stop VS2017 closing my master solution when I want to connect to either of subrepositories. Super annoying...